# How to change a JButton color when I hover over it but change it permanently to something else even if I hover afterwards when I click it?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, mouselistener

I want to have a JButton on which when I hover over it, it should turn green and when the mouse exits it should go back to default but when I click on it should turn yellow and stay yellow whether or not I hover over it. Thanks.

I have already tried the mouselistener method.

```
     public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
           bakery.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
     }

     public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt){
        bakery.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("control"));
     }

     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt){
        bakery.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);          
        }
  });
```

I expected that once I click it should stay yellow but it seems so when I exit the button area it goes back to default and when I hover again it gets green again. Which makes sense according to the mouselistener but I have no idea how to get the result I actually desire.

Comment: You might want to consider having a look at the `ButtonModel` instead of using a `MouseListener`.  You need to define a "state" which can be used to determine if the  button should be updated on mouse enter/exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want the button to stay yellow, until clicked again?

Try this:

```
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    if (bakery.getBackground() != Color.YELLOW) { // skip if already yellow
        bakery.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    if (bakery.getBackground() != Color.YELLOW) { // skip if already yellow
        bakery.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("control"));
    }
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if (bakery.getBackground() != Color.YELLOW) {
        // The first click will set yellow
        bakery.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    } else {
        // A second click clears the yellow.
        bakery.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("control"));
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it, I did not want to change it back to default once clicked again but stay yellow all the time once clicked and that did it! Thanks a bunch.